# Pass the api key along with the request in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I have two Rails apps. One generates the API key, contains the api and requires the api key for some controller actions.

The second app is just an app for interacting with said api.

My question is, how do I - in the second app's controller - say "post to the first app's controller action and oh by the way pass this api key though for authentication"

I am not using oauth or anything else, just simple

```
  def restrict_api_access
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
      @api_key = ApiKey.find_by(api_key: token)
    end unless current_user
  end
```

So how do I - on each post , put or update (or even) delete - pass the api key along with the action request?

Comment: Use a custom HTTP header in each request for the API key

Comment: what about using HTTParty ?

Comment: @PinnyM can you provide an example please?

Comment: The example would be specific to the client being used to access the API.  For instance, using cURL: `curl -IH "Authorization: Token token=api-token-goes-here" http://localhost:3000/some-valid-route`.  If you are using a different client (ruby or otherwise), please post what it is.